# Confusion in topology Notation

Tags: general-topology

This  is  Question  is taken  from  [choose the correct option $1)$ $\mathbb{R} \times \{1\}$ $2)$ $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159588/choose-the-correct-option-1-mathbbr-times-1-2-mathbbr2)

I have  some  confusing  in notation . My  first confusion

what  is  $\langle x, 1\rangle$ ?

$2$nd  confusion is that   why they  have  written  like this  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I understand your confusion, that looks like a span. I think they just mean the cartesian product of some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1$. I'd usually write this as the tuple $(x,1) \in \mathbb{R} \times \{1\}$.

2) The $\langle y,z\rangle$ is a tuple in $\mathbb{R}^2$ this time, just like above. I would usually write '$\colon$' or '$\vert$' in place of their '$;$'. So the ball $B_\epsilon$ consists of points 
$$ B_\epsilon = \{(y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2\colon (y-x)^2 + (z-1)^2 \leq \epsilon\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.
$$

Comment: thanks  u so much @ bounceback

Comment: You're very welcome